# Error in adding css module to webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am trying to add css modules to webpack in my react project. I added it like this

```
{
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: [
                    'style?sourceMap',
                    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
                ]
            },
```

But I am getting compile error saying

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/video.js/dist/video-js.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'font/VideoJS.eot' in /home/apurv/Downloads/Frontend-Master-master/node_modules/video.js/dist
 @ ./~/css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!./~/video.js/dist/video-js.css 6:984-1011
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I already have a stylus loader in webpack and it is working fine

```
{
                test: /\.styl$/, 
                loader: [ 
                    'isomorphic-style-loader',
                    'css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
                    'stylus?sourceMap'
                ].join('!')
            },
```

How can I solve this error?

I already have a loader for eot files

```
{
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
```

And when I use css loader like this(below), the error doesn't come.

```
{
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
```

I have already installed css-loader and style-loader in my package.json file.

Comment: In your error message it is showing error that it can not resolve font `font/VideoJS.eot`, so I think you will need a loader to load that font. You can use `file-loader` to use fonts. See this [link](https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/22/working-with-fonts-with-webpack/)

Comment: I already have a loader for that  {
     test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
     loader: 'file-loader'
    },